# What is the best way to store variables or credentials in python?

Tags: python-3.x, credentials

I am doing a project, where the credentials and machine details to be stored in some file and later accessed by many other files/modules/classes.

Can all the credentials stored in separate file ?

```
class Credentials:
   username1 = 'nfkjljflgflgfgfg'
   password1 = 'fhrfkfhfkfk'
   username2 = 'febvkfvof'
   password2 = 'mvbnodeurv'
```

This may not correct. But, I welcome if any better ideas of storing them or if someone can help in modifying above (whichever you feel best).

Comment: Generally speaking, it is never a good idea to store plain credentials, anywhere. Does your project support key-based or hash-based authentication?

Comment: @PrateekDewan I agree. I am planning to encrypt and decrypt that particular credentials file. Right now, thinking what could be the best way to create such file and access them all over project.

Comment: In that case, you're free to use whatever type of file you like. A pickle file is probably the easiest. You can `pickle.dump()` the credentials in a Python-compatible datatype (let's say `dict`) directly onto a pickle file, and load it back with a single `pickle.load()`.

Comment: Thank you @PrateekDewan. Could you help me with defining credentials in class and accessing from any other.

Comment: Creating a Python class and sharing it across might be tedious. Relative imports will probably drive you nuts. Just use a pickle file and use the absolute path of the file, and you can access it from anywhere on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a config file of some sort, and read in using configparser. The advantage here is your config file can be distributed across multiple projects and multiple different languages.

Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html for more information, but in general your config file would look like the following

```
[Credentials]
username1 = nfkjljflgflgfgfg
password1 = fhrfkfhfkfk
username2 = febvkfvof
password2 = mvbnodeurv
```

You can then read it with

```
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read('config.ini')
>>> config['Credentials']['username1']
nfkjljflgflgfgfg
```

Most importantly though, as others have mentioned, please encrypt your usernames and passwords.